# Can one batch requests with google-auth-library?

Tags: node.js, google-authentication, google-auth-library-nodejs

The way I have been using the client thus far has been like

```js
      client = new OAuth2Client(
        process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        "http://localhost:5000/oauth2callback"
      );

      client.setCredentials({refresh_token: getRefreshToken(user)});
      let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=myquery';
      client.request({url}).then((response) => {
        doSomethingWith(response);
      });
```

Since `response` holds a list of message ids, I will have to use [`users.messages.get`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) to get the actual data for each message. I would prefer not to do hundreds of separate requests just for one query. Is there a way to batch the `users.messages.get` requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google APIs [batching requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) feature. Here's an example function that accepts the array of message IDs and the client as params and then does a batch request to the `users.messages.get` endpoint.

```
const batchGetMessages = (messageIds = [], oAuth2Client) => {
  const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/gmail/v1';
  const boundary = 'message_batch_demo';
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': `multipart/mixed; boundary=${boundary}`
  };

  let data = '';
  for (const messageId of messageIds) {
    data += `--${boundary}\r\nContent-Type: application/http\r\n\r\n`;
    data += `GET /gmail/v1/users/me/messages/${messageId}`;
    data += '\r\n';
  }
  data += `--${boundary}--`;

  return oAuth2Client.request({
    url,
    headers,
    data,
    method: 'POST'
  });
};
```